# Collisions and the kinetic theory of gases as discussed in Feynman's lectures

Tags: collision, kinetic-theory

In *The Feynman Lectures on Physics* Volume $1$, Chapter $39$: *The Kinetic Theory of Gases*, section *Temperature and kinetic energy* (which can be found in [this](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_39.html) page), the author discusses the subject of collisions within a gas. More specifically, he spoke about a box containing two gases, each one having atoms with masses $m_{1}$, $m_{2}$ and velocities $v_{1}$, $v_{2}$. He first said,

> Let us suppose that we have two molecules, of
>   different mass, colliding, and that the collision is viewed in the center-of-mass
>   (CM) system. In order to remove a complication, we look at the collision in the
>   CM. As we know from the laws of collision, by the conservation of momentum
>   and energy, after the molecules collide the only way they can move is such that
>   each maintains its own original speed—and they just change their direction.. Suppose, for a
>   moment, that we watch all the collisions with the CM at rest. Suppose we
>   imagine that they are all initially moving horizontally. Of course, after the first
>   collision some of them are moving at an angle. In other words, if they were all
>   going horizontally, then at least some would later be moving vertically. Now in
>   some other collision, they would be coming in from another direction, and then
>   they would be twisted at still another angle. So even if they were completely
>   organized in the beginning, they would get sprayed around at all angles, and
>   then the sprayed ones would get sprayed some more, and sprayed some more,
>   and sprayed some more. Ultimately, what will be the distribution? Answer: It
>   will be equally likely to find any pair moving in any direction in space. After that
>   further collisions could not change the distribution.
>
> They are equally likely to go in all directions, but how do we say that? There
>   is of course no likelihood that they will go in any specific direction, because a
>   specific direction is too exact, so we have to talk about per unit “something.”
>   The idea is that any area on a sphere centered at a collision point will have just
>   as many molecules going through it as go through any other equal area on the
>   sphere. So the result of the collisions will be to distribute the directions so that
>   equal areas on a sphere will have equal probabilities.

He then said the following about the angle $\theta$ between any $\textbf{v}_{1}$  and $\textbf{v}_{2}$ ,

> the cosine of
>   the angle $\theta$ between any two directions is equally likely to be anything from $−1$ to $+1$.

The following and final part, that I had some troubles linking to the the two sections above, reads

> Next, we have to worry about the actual case, where we do not have the
>   collision in the CM system, but we have two atoms which are coming together
>   with vector velocities $\textbf{v}_{1}$ and $\textbf{v}_{2}$. What happens now? We can analyze this
>   collision with the vector velocities $\textbf{v}_{1}$ and $\textbf{v}_{1}$ in the following way: We first say
>   that there is a certain CM; the velocity of the CM is given by the “average”
>   velocity, with weights proportional to the masses, so the velocity of the CM 
>   is $\textbf{v}_{CM} = (m_{1}\textbf{v}_{1} + m_{2}\textbf{v}_{2})/(m_{1} + m_{2})$. If we watch this collision in the CM
>   system, then we see a collision just like that in Fig. 39-3,

[image]

> with a certain relative velocity $\textbf{w}$ coming in. The relative velocity is just $\textbf{v}_{1} − \textbf{v}_{2}$. Now the idea is that, first, the whole CM is moving, and in the CM there is a relative velocity  $\textbf{w}$, and the molecules collide and come off in some new direction. All this happens while the CM keeps right on moving, without any change.
>
> Now then, what is the distribution resulting from this? From our previous
>   argument we conclude this: that at equilibrium, *all directions for $\textbf{w}$ are equally likely, relative to the direction of the motion of the CM.* There will be no particular correlation, in the end, between the direction of the motion of the relative velocity and that of the motion of the CM. Of course, if there were, the collisions would spray it about, so it is all sprayed around. So the cosine of the angle between $\textbf{w}$ and $\textbf{v}_{CM}$ is zero on the average. That is, $$\langle \textbf{w} \cdot \textbf{v}_{CM} \rangle = 0.$$

$1.$ The final section starts by saying that we need to deal with the collisions in a general case, not in the specific CM frame, but then goes right after that to reintroduce the CM again; does it make sense?

$2.$ He said that $\cos(\theta)$, with $\theta = (\textbf{v}_{1}, \textbf{v}_{2})$, is uniformly distributed over $[-1, 1]$, but this also implies that the cosine of the angle between $\textbf{w}=\textbf{v}_{1} − \textbf{v}_{2}$ and *any* other direction must also be equally likely to be anything from $-1$ to $1$; so is $\langle \textbf{w} \cdot \textbf{a}\rangle = 0$ really only true for $\textbf{a}= \textbf{v}_{CM}$?

Comment: Question about the same part of the Feynman lectures and similar discussion:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/523729/59023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, he initially considers the rest frame of the CM, but then considers the case where the CM moves at constant velocity. But there is not really a difference between these cases. We can always work with the velocities in the rest frame, then add the velocity of the CM if we want the velocities in a frame where the CM is moving.

For the second question, I think you are correct, because for generic velocities $\mathbf{v}_1$, $\mathbf{v}_2$, the CM velocity $\mathbf{v}_{CM}$ is an arbitrary vector.